# How to read and write x86 flags registers directly?

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

From what I've read, seems like there are 9 different flags. Is it possible to read/change them directly? I know I can know for example if the zero flag is set after doing a cmp/jmp instruction, but I'm asking if it's possible to do something like

```
mov eax, flags
```

or something.

Also, for writing, is it possible to set them by hand?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register has a map of which flag is where after `pushf` or `lahf`.

Comment: Related: [How can I set or clear overflow flag in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798572/how-can-i-set-or-clear-overflow-flag-in-x86-assembly) for clearing / setting OF with either PUSHF/AND/POPF, or an instructions sequence that writes all flags including OF with a known values.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Some flags can be set or cleared directly with specific instructions:

- [CLC](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/CLC.htm), [STC](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/STC.htm), and [CMC](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/CMC.htm): clear, set, and complement the carry flag
- [CLI](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/CLI.htm) and [STI](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/STI.htm): clear and set the interrupt flag (which should be done atomically)
- [CLD](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/CLD.htm) and [STD](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/STD.htm): clear and set the direction flag

For reading and writing the sign, zero, auxiliary carry, parity, and carry flags, you can use [LAHF](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/LAHF.htm) to load the lower 8 bits (those 5 flags plus 3 indeterminate bits) into the AH register, and you can use [SAHF](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/SAHF.htm) to store those values from AH back into the flags register.

You can also use the [PUSHF](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/PUSHF.htm) instruction to push the flags onto the stack, read and modify them on the stack, and then use the [POPF](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/POPF.htm)<sup>1</sup> instruction to store them back into the flags register.

Note that you cannot set the VM and RF flags with POPF -- they retain their previous values.  Similarly, you can only change the I/O privilege level when executing at privilege level 0, and the interrupt flag can only be changed when executing at a privilege level at least as privileged as the I/O privilege level.

---

**Footnote 1:**

Note that `popf` is quite slow on modern CPUs; see [Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) optimization guide and instruction tables.  It's microcoded because in kernel mode it's able to change IF and AC, and IO privilege level.  We suffer the penalty regardless of mode on current CPUs because the decoders aren't mode-sensitive.

If possible, use lahf/sahf instead of pushf/popf for performance, or save a single flag you care about like `setc al` then later `add al, 255` to set `CF = (AL!=0)`.  Or `setnc al` / `sub al, 1` or whatever.  Sequences to set or clear SF or OF based on a 0 or 1 register are also straightforward, with/without inverting the flag.

Comment: More precisely: the Intel manual classifies each flag as either: status, control or system. The system flags cannot be modified by userland applications.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the pushf and popf instructions which will push the flags onto the stack, you can modify them, and then pop them back off.

Answer (score 8):

If you need only the lower byte of the flags register (which contains SF,ZF,AF,PF,CF), then there is the odd but convenient instruction LAHF (ha ha), which loads the bottom 8 bits of the flags register into AH, and its counterpart SAHF to store AH into flags.

 
For the carry flag specifically, x86 offers CLC, STC and CMC, to clear, set, and complement the carry flag, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is using *pushfd/pushfw and pop (r16/r32)*.

If you want to move `eflags` into `eax`, use code below.

```
pushfd                 # push eflags into stack
pop %eax               # pop it into %eax
```

Or, if you only want the first 16 bits from `eflags`:

```
pushfw
pop %ax
```

In most assemblers (at least GAS and NASM, likely others), `pushf` without an explicit operand-size defaults to the mode you're in.  e.g. `pushfq` in 64-bit mode.  You'd normally only need an explicit operand-size if you wanted to use `pushfd` in 16-bit mode to match a 32-bit `pop`.  But it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Why would you mov+add instead of `pop %eax` like a normal person?  POP is faster and smaller than MOV + ADD.

Comment: `pushf` defaults to `pushfw` in a 16-bit code segment but may be an alias to `pushfd` in a 32-bit code segment.

Comment: @babu646: your edit implies that `pushf` is always 16-bit.  It's not.  GAS assembles `pushf` to use an operand-size matching the mode, i.e. just to a `9c` byte.  So in `gcc -m32 -c foo.s`, it assembles as `pushfd`.  Or in `-m64` code, it assembles as `pushfq` (still just a `9c` byte).  Same for NASM `-felf32` vs. `-felf64`.  (This answer uses AT&T.)  There might be some assemblers where `pushf` is a 16-bit push even in 32 or 64-bit mode, but not GAS or NASM.  Or maybe you're assuming 16-bit mode where `pushf` is always `pushfw`, and `pop %eax` would need an operand-size prefix.

Comment: @ecm: That mistake was introduced by an edit.  I've made an edit to fix it.

Comment: For `__asm volatile("\t pushfd");` gcc produces: `Error: no such instruction: `pushfd'`. How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

**SETcc**

This instruction family is another way to observe some flags / combination of flags.

It sets the value of a byte based on the individual FLAGS.

E.g., for `CF`:

```
stc
setc al
; al == 1

clc
setc al
; al == 0
```

[Runnable GitHub upstream with assertions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/6aa2f783a8a18589ae66e85f781f86b08abb3397/userland/arch/x86_64/jcc.S).

**Jcc**

This instruction family is of course another possibility for certain flags, and could be used to implement `SETcc`:

```
jc set
mov al, 0
jmp end
set:
mov al, 1
end:
```

[Runnable GitHub upstream with assertions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/6aa2f783a8a18589ae66e85f781f86b08abb3397/userland/arch/x86_64/setcc.S).

Answer (score 1):

- LAHF:  loads status flags into AH
- Copies the low byte of the EFLAGS register including Sign, Zero, and Carry flags.
- Save a copy of the flags in a variable for safekeeping

  ```
  .data
   saveflags BYTE ? 
  .code 
   lahf ; load flags into AH 
   mov saveflags,ah ; save them into a variable
  ```
- SAHF:  stores AH into status flags
- Copies AH into the low byte of the EFLAGS register
- Retrieve the value of flags stored earlier

  ```
  .code
   mov ah, saveflags ; load save flags into AH 
   sahf ; copy into flags register
  ```