# How to change the eflags register value in GDB?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, flags

`set $eflags` does not change `eflags` value.

The old `eflags` value remains after eg. `=>$set $eflag=0x243` [this is just an example input].

Alternatively, is there any way to set individual flags of `eflags`?

I'm looking for something like: `set ZF[zero flag]`. Is there a gdb command to do that?

Comment: eflags [ ZF ] should do..

Comment: I got "Undefined command: "eflags".  Try "help"." with "eflags [ ZF ]". Can you give an example of this command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set ($eflags)=0x243
```

worked in my tests for any hex value.

Comment: In GDB 7.7.1, the parenthesis don't seem to be required: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31339372/895245

Answer (score 24):

`set $eflags` without parenthesis works in GDB 7.7.1

To set an individual flag, use its index. E.g., ZF is the 6th bit, so we can set it with:

```
set $ZF = 6                 # define a GDB variable: no effect on registers
set $eflags |= (1 << $ZF)   # set bit 6 in EFLAGS, the ZF bit.
```

or just directly:

```
set $eflags |= (1 << 6)
```

The same goes for all other bitwise operations: [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

```
# Clear
set $eflags &= ~(1 << $ZF)

# Toggle
set $eflags ^= (1 << $ZF)
```

What causes confusion is that many bits are either reserved, cannot be modified directly by any instruction, or cannot be modified from user mode, see also: [How to read and write x86 flags registers directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406783/flags-registers-can-we-read-or-write-them-directly) and so GDB does not touch them.

For example:

```
(gdb) set $eflags = 0
(gdb) i r eflags
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
(gdb) set $eflags = 0xFFFFFFFF
(gdb) i r eflags
eflags         0x54fd7  [ CF PF AF ZF SF TF IF DF OF NT RF AC ]
```

`0x202` in binary is:

```
0010 0000 0010
```

`0x54fd7` in binary is:

```
0101  0100 1111 1101 0111
```

TODO understand why each of those bits were set or not, by looking at the manual http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf and GDB source code.

Ones that I understand:

- all reserved registers were left at their fixed value: 1 for bit 1, and 0 for bits 3, 5, 15 and 22-31

Comment: What does the set $eflags |= (1 << $ZF) command do? Why is set $ZF=6 not enough?

Comment: @user3364161 just to avoid magic constants in the code, and auto document what they mean. ZF=6 would work as well of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to set all flags in `eflags` register. So some bits reserved and must be 0.(3,5,15,22 and greater) bit 1 must be 1. There is `rflags` too. But all `hi dword` is zero.  So there is no need to use `rflags` instead of `eflags` for all operations changed flags. But I know peoples that use free bits for own usage.

More suitable `rflags hi dword`. So in 64-bit architecture enough free registers to use. But in 32-bit architecture, no. So strongly recommend to do so.

Because in future architectures some of these bits may be used. But these flags are not touched from changing 32-bit to 64-bit. If the only register that may be not changed at all. So all possible reasons for any case already used. I don't imagine any situation that may be used  some additional flag don't be used till now. It may be to some cardinal processor architecture change. I don't think some decide to do so for obvious reason all soft must be thrown out and rewritten from the very beginning. It's extremely hard and huge work.

Comment: The original poster didn't say they wanted to set all bits, but specific ones or a group (they gave 0x243 as an example). They wanted a clean way to set individual flags.

Answer (score -1):

```
eflags [ ZF ]
```

And if you want to set arbitrary value use this

eflags  0x42

Comment: Use `set ($eflags)|=0x42` to set [ZF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_flag). Tested.