# How can I set or clear overflow flag in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

I want to write a simple code (or algorithm) to set/clear overflow flag. For setting OF, I know that I can use signed values. But how can I clear that?

Comment: perform an operation that never would create an overflow? e.g. `mov ax, 1; inc ax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions.

For instance, **`test al, al`** will clear the `OF` flag without affecting register contents.

---

Or, if you don't want to affect the other flags, you can just directly modify the `*FLAGS` register.  For example, in 32-bit, this would look like:

```
pushfd                   ; Push EFLAGS onto the stack
and dword [esp], ~0x800  ; Clear bit 11 (OF)
popfd                    ; Pop the modified result back into EFLAGS
```

---

<sub>Edit:  Changed `or al, al` to `test al, al` per [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)' recommendation.  (The effects are the same but the latter is better for performance reasons)</sub>

Comment: `test al,al` is a better idiom for setting flags according to the contents of a register.  It only writes flags, so it doesn't increase the length of the dependency chain involving `al`.  +1 for the `pushf`/`popf` method, though.  (Since `sahf`/`lahf` doesn't include `OF`).

Comment: Good point about `or` and `test`; I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Provided:

- you have a register whose content you don't care about,
- you must to preserve `CF`-Flag

### Best solution to clear OF (sar):

Say register is `al`. (`setc` only with byte registers r/8)

```
; clear OF-Flag, preserve CF
setc al
sar al, 1
```

Note: this is good because it has no partial flag updates, which may cause stalls. (`sar  xx, 1` writes all flags, not leaving any unmodified, unlike `inc`/`dec`) c.f. [Intel Optimization Guide, 3.5.2.6: Partial Flag Register Stalls](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9e/bc/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf), but note that modern Intel CPUs don't have partial-flag stalls or flag-merging at all: instructions that read FLAGS [just read either or both of CF or the SPAZO group as 2 separate inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867597/what-is-a-partial-flag-stall). (That's why `cmovbe` is still 2 uops on Broadwell and later: it needs CF and ZF.  https://uops.info/)

Source:[Intel Documentation SAR p.1234](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

### General solution (inc/dec):

Say register is `al`. (works with r/8, r/16, r/32, r/64)

```
; set OF-Flag, preserve CF
mov al, 0x7F
inc al

; clear OF-Flag, preserve CF
mov al, 0x0
inc al
```

Source:[Intel Documentation INC p.551](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

### Alternatively (adox):

Different apporach, if you can assume:

- an `adx` enabled processor (You check cpu flags with `grep adx /proc/cpuinfo`)

Say register is `eax`. (need r64/r32)

```
; clear OF-Flag, preserve CF
mov eax, 0x0
adox eax, eax

; set OF-Flag, preserve CF
mov eax, 0xFFFFFFFF
adox eax, eax
```

Note: Don't try to replace `mov` with `xor` (or similar) since that will clear `CF`

Source:[Intel Documentation ADOX p.150](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)

Comment: You need the register not to be `-1` beforehand.  `0xFFFF...` + 1 wraps, producing carry-out (which ADOX will output as OF=1).  But yes, if you set a different value beforehand, that's an interesting way to set/clear just OF without touching other flags.

Comment: good point. also `adox` cannot handle immediate values anyway. I edited the code.

Comment: Modern Intel CPUs don't have partial-flag stalls or even partial-flag merging uops; see @Bee's answer on [What is a Partial Flag Stall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49867597).  I edited your answer to include that, since you're discussing optimization.

Answer (score 2):

[`popf` is quite slow (like one per 20 cycles on Skylake)](http://agner.org/optimize/); if you need to clear or set OF then ideally do it as a side-effect of an ALU instruction, especially one you were going to use anyway for a useful computation you know won't or will overflow.  (One that will overflow is usually harder to find, unlike for CF where you can always just `sub` instead of `add` with a constant that wraps almost all the way around for all inputs except a very small range).

If you need to set/clear *just* OF without affecting other condition-codes for some reason, then yes, `pushf`/`popf` is the way to go.  `lahf` / `sahf` doesn't get OF, because OF is bit 11 in EFLAGS, outside the low 8.

---

**`test al,al` (or any same,same register) clears OF and CF**, just like [comparing / subtracting zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806).  Other flags are usefully set according to the value.

**`xor eax,eax` clears EAX, and clears OF/SF/CF, sets ZF/PF**.  You often need a zeroed register anyway, so if you need OF clear (e.g. for the start of an [`adox` extended-precision chain](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/ADOX.html)), then kill 2 birds with one stone and arrange your code so the last flag-setting instruction is the xor-zeroing.

In x86-64, you can also trust that using `add` on a pointer + length doesn't cross over the middle of unsigned virtual address space, and thus clears `OF`.  But that assumption could break on future CPUs with fully 64-bit virtual addresses, because then there'd be no [hole in virtual address space around the signed-wraparound boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687805/should-pointer-comparisons-be-signed-or-unsigned-in-64-bit-x86), so a single contiguous array could span it.  And that can already happen in 32-bit code, running under a 64-bit kernel or a 32-bit kernel that doesn't use a 2G:2G kernel:user split of virtual address space.

---

**`xor eax, eax` / `cmp al, -128` sets OF, and only takes 4 bytes of code**.  It's is probably the cheapest way, and unlike `sub` or whatever, it doesn't write any partial registers (or any full registers).  It still leaves EAX zeroed.

[`0 -  -128` wraps to `-128`, i.e. signed OF](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt).  An 8-bit 2's complement integer can only represent values from `-128..+127`.  The most-negative number is a special case, and has no proper inverse.  It's its own absolute value / negative, or more properly those functions overflow.  (Or you could treat the absolute value operation as having signed input and unsigned output, so the result is +128, i.e. 0x80.  x86 doesn't have an integer abs instruction (prepare a `-x`, then test/cmov), but with SSSE3 it does have vector integer [`pabsb`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PABSB:PABSW:PABSD:PABSQ.html))

For any known value in AL other than `-1`, there's a `cmp al, imm8` that will set OF.  For any value from 0..127, cmp `al, -128` wraps.  For any value from -2..-128, `cmp al, +127` wraps and thus sets OF.  For `-1`, subtracting 127 will only take you to -128.  Subtracting -128 takes you up to +127.  Unfortunately I don't think there's a single-instruction way to set OF without a known value in a register.

It doesn't *have* to be `al`, but there's a 2-byte special encoding of `cmp al,imm8`.  Other 8 or 32-bit registers can use the normal 3-byte encoding.

---

Without clobbering any registers, and no known constants, this is 6 bytes:

```
push   rax
xor    eax,eax
cmp    al, -128
pop    rax
```

This does clobber the other condition codes, but it's faster than `pushf`/`popf`.  Normally you can clobber something, though, or else you can't clobber the stack.

---

#### Toggle OF

```
setno al              # OF=0 -> AL=1           OF=1 -> AL=0
cmp   al, -127        # 1 - -127 = 128 = -128     0 - -127 = +127
```

Comment: what's the point of lahf and sahf when it doesn't affect all the flags? why do those instructions exist?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I don't understand the 8086 design decision to put OF outside the flags affected by LAHF/SAHF, especially since there are still reserved bits in the low 8 of FLAGS.  I think there was some intent to make it easy / mechanical to port 8080 asm source to 8086, so this may explain it.  (You or I should ask on retrocomputing about this design decision)  One major use of LAHF is to set condition codes from the high byte of the x87 FP status word, e.g. `fstsw [bp-2]` / `pop ax` / `lahf`. Or on [286 and later](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html) `fstsw ax`/`lahf`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Oops, that's `fstsw ax` / `SAHF` (store AH into FLAGS) / `ja` or `jb` or `jp`.  (The LAHF/SAHF mnemonics seem backwards to me; written in that order, my brain thinks load AH *into* FLAGS, not *from* FLAGS).  Anyway, this is *why* the more recent `fucomi` and SSE `ucomiss` / `ucomisd` instructions set flags like an unsigned compare, with PF set on unordered (NaN); for compat with how [the legacy method lined up the C3/C2/C0 bits in the x87 status word with bits in FLAGS](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap7.htm#ficom).