# How can I set overflow flag in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to write a simple code (or algorithm) to set/clear overflow flag.can you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406783/flags-registers-can-we-read-or-write-them-directly

Answer (score 2):

Many instructions clear `OF` as a side effect, for example `test`. As such you can write something like `test eax, eax` and that will clear `OF`, although it will affect other flags. You didn't specify whether that's allowed.

To set `OF` you can perform some operation that will set it. For example, add 1 to the biggest positive number: `mov al, 0x7f; add al, 1`

Alternatively, you can make a copy of the flags on the stack using `pushf`, modify it to your liking and then get it back using `popf`.

Comment: You should consider deleting your answer here and moving it to the duplicate. Or flagging this question and asking a moderator to merge all of its answers into the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

To set the [Overflow flag(OF) - Bit 11 of EFLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29#Flags) use (in MASM syntax)

```
pushfd                   ; mov EFLAGS to stack
bts dword ptr [esp], 11  ; set OF flag
popfd                    ; write it back to status register
```

and, respectively, use the following to reset the OF flag:

```
pushfd                   ; mov EFLAGS to stack
btr dword ptr [esp], 11  ; reset OF flag
popfd                    ; write it back to status register
```

Comment: `or` or `and` with a memory destination is fewer uops than `bts [mem], imm` on Intel CPUs.  Even with an immediate bit count, `bts` and friends with a memory destination aren't as efficient, so generally avoid them with memory operands other than when you need an atomic (`lock`) test-and-set.

Comment: `pushf` pushes that `FLAGS` register. To push `EFLAGS`, better use `pushfd`.

Comment: ["The PUSHF (push flags) and PUSHFD (push flags double) mnemonics reference the same opcode...."](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSHF:PUSHFD:PUSHFQ.html). I changed the answer anyway to improve the emphasis.

Comment: @Nubok: even if it did only push FLAGS, `OF` is in the low 16 bits of EFLAGS, i.e. FLAGS, so this code works.  `btr` and `popf` are both quite slow, and `btr dword ptr[]` isn't guaranteed to load/store a whole dword anyway, so you could get a store-forwarding stall either way.  `or` or `and mem, imm32` to set or clear might take an extra 2 or 3 code bytes, though.  But if you want min code size to set `OF` without clobbering regs, `push eax` / `xor eax,eax` / `sub al, -128` (2 bytes) / `pop eax` should do it in 6B total, vs. 7B for this answer which also avoids clobbering any other flags.

Comment: @zx485
Based on your source you it indeed seems to be a common convention that these instructions are treated as synonyms to each other. I had the other convention that is mentioned there in mind: "The PUSHF instruction is intended for use when the operand-size attribute is 16 and the PUSHFD instruction for when the operand-size attribute is 32. Some assemblers may force the operand size to 16 when PUSHF is used and to 32 when PUSHFD is used."