# Is there a good reason why GCC would generate jump to jump just over one cheap instruction?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization

I was benchmarking some counting in a loop code.
g++ was used with -O2 code and I noticed that it has some perf problems when some condition is true in 50% of the cases. I assumed that may mean that code does unnecessary jumps(since clang produces faster code so it is not some fundamental limitation).

What I find in this asm output funny is that code jumps over one simple add.

```
=> 0x42b46b <benchmark_many_ints()+1659>:       movslq (%rdx),%rax
   0x42b46e <benchmark_many_ints()+1662>:       mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x42b471 <benchmark_many_ints()+1665>:       imul   %r9,%rax
   0x42b475 <benchmark_many_ints()+1669>:       shr    $0xe,%rax
   0x42b479 <benchmark_many_ints()+1673>:       and    $0x1ff,%eax
   0x42b47e <benchmark_many_ints()+1678>:       cmp    (%r10,%rax,4),%ecx
   0x42b482 <benchmark_many_ints()+1682>:       jne    0x42b488 <benchmark_many_ints()+1688>
   0x42b484 <benchmark_many_ints()+1684>:       add    $0x1,%rbx
   0x42b488 <benchmark_many_ints()+1688>:       add    $0x4,%rdx
   0x42b48c <benchmark_many_ints()+1692>:       cmp    %rdx,%r8
   0x42b48f <benchmark_many_ints()+1695>:       jne    0x42b46b <benchmark_many_ints()+1659>
```

Note that my question is not how to fix my code, I am just asking if there is a reason why a good compiler at O2 would generate jne instruction to jump over 1 cheap instruction.
I ask because from [what I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406783/how-to-read-and-write-x86-flags-registers-directly) one could "simply" get the comparison result and use that to without jumps increment the counter(rbx in my example) by 0 or 1.

edit: source:
https://godbolt.org/z/v0Iiv4

Comment: Probably a good idea to post the C/C++ code that resulted in this assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the source (from a Godbolt link in a comment which you should really edit into your question) is:

```
const auto cnt = std::count_if(lookups.begin(), lookups.end(),[](const auto& val){
    return buckets[hash_val(val)%16] == val;});
```

I didn't check the libstdc++ headers to see if `count_if` is implemented with an `if() { count++; }`, or if it uses a ternary to encourage branchless code.  Probably a conditional.  (The compiler can choose either, but a ternary is more likely to compile to a branchless `cmovcc` or `setcc`.)

---

**It looks like gcc overestimated the cost of branchless for this code with generic tuning**.  `-mtune=skylake` (implied by `-march=skylake`) gives us branchless code for this regardless of `-O2` vs. `-O3`, or `-fno-tree-vectorize` vs. `-ftree-vectorize`.  (On [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAViAIzkA2AhgHaioCkATAEK8%2B5AM7oArqVTYQAcl4BmAm1RMxOANRd5AYRalSLAJ5bcXAAwBBBUpVrsmnSybAyxJAFsT5qz0XLVGlraqEik6GzoXpbW/nYO2gTowkSk2Cye8qbRvjYB9kEAbtioJKRRVtl%2BtjhBicmp6eViwkrA6mzp2MIADixS6smYWgKWza3tnT199oMgaKHhkfIjFRYA9GvqAOpIhgMEAF7YAPpE6gBmZOpESPZE2O7dZHp7SslpmOro5%2BpKRABsABZTloAGLeDbqbToR4EJjjS6kdQsdTyHgAWgARsR1ABJADKFnUAHc4Ux1MACEV1IZxMj1EgWMIkCS3NdbgyCMAWfQAJzqbFEYTIpjko5hbwYNjvAAe3SRLSOpwZTKQxwKTggf1%2BAEouAB2FbqY3qVJECRsdQQRUnIhanUAKgArAAOfU8ei%2BeT/fVmJ30eS8p1%2BnUOUyZdR84beA0AERjlmSLCIBFQ6ilsvlyP0RlqbCI5HoZhM7TE7mEBr4jB45Hk8nIgPITqd5H%2B5H1HfILvIvMLZn7cej0UsGfucqRegMxh0f3Ikf%2BJeA2CIx0xYlQAGtl8IIHrDd4Tdmp3mC/OS6lhGImERK4PlgeTYirdqCA5Y8Xlr8gvQF8sCIJBD3I1DxNC8rxvJ0%2BH/J1YzfUtyy4SDixgociRNQdLEPJ8IBYMQSHUDUmBAeDhCAh8QNNLpwMQvhGWZdVNUIvUeH9BcYLgwjUMPDC0ONM0LUoy9r1QninC5DodyBUNR2wccj1zGd8znH8SzXTdtzgpcVzUrchV3ETLG1GhmhXDAxHza0iEwOYihKMgTxLXh/iYdB0A3MRulIzR90wk1R2RPD0HTfM4NmNBxHzY4CHOCAXLcjzhAAOkxbBKTYXc5zi9zPMS7A2EwDKaMQ2MIH83CSCcginDI3yKP40hLR07caLotVCIgJjeFY4q3y0WDOPvfVYz1e9aso80GuCm9RqsIaEwsbUIhXdwWCUfToh83iLiuUrwmSAL8MI4imqFUNbzGw8zLOIIgiq8kbp0dQ8swJguPQuaxrC2zSgciMsoSt7jWwl84I/Pgv0en8HSLHhAWhsxYejfhBAIM7Noo41/py7pmjVTE%2Bg3CB0XoEbgIorGkpx%2Bj8c3CA2DLCtIIMfL9JY%2Bny0Sm19Jg0nyO8%2BNhy2srAuuY4k1Ia75FgsKQjCCI5iQLk1QvdBVBTcJjhUdBNzmCJiX0mbLr2s5yqC1AQr6gYrLmMzIui2LXOypKUrSjL1Ap3KWZ1cgipg3bpRNwLKs69GMfqxr110xnaNVBimA66qupU9i%2BstgaBCG3mLvQ3zzF5YX8JXZ7Qut%2BY5fQBWleOFW1cSNhNZcnWQD1g3gLzgugsIc4fktzAJGTOvNaZabtBlhZ5ZAdwyQIYRinCTAK0yCAi/y9R0VF8WiCzoXxEl7Rbt4Hh3cdhLrkdzQeCPh7tHULvzkS227TOnQD8v9QOc0J1tDYQ%2BDJ3vD4ivx4N0bAkgL5XxfpDRKZgHTmyIGsCAMM4ZIIdGiZ%2B%2B9HrPVeobUCy4BJgxjB9CwMhvZERkE6GQ5A2CyDMJQiuMh97I34AMcQkh8i%2BHoJQogNCSHew3CAYMzBZCAkoe4EAHZEpun1FImRHYXTdmoTIWh5B6GUOECAMw5BuFKJIeQOAsAUC7xxgWKgu1YRMFAQwcg2BCClCscSAw3RZCcNIbIChVCeEqNkAoegrIbjqBlC6f46IgTplYBwdQ/xoHQK4TwnU3tbgsBwKQagriZAiPIGIy%2BiVPQekvrkgpNZFHKNUSIDRWi4l8JAIGaBZgOz/A9ICQEvIzB1hrGQ%2BQlDil0NkLEnR3t9HIHCuY0BlBqAYBGSk4ALoaznDhPcUg6iICYk8diDopBDDOMoRM9weUiAAHk2BME2To8gOAVocAsZ4wgqQShUi6J42SxQ8LSBkJwyg%2BZsBkOUSkAgYi3m6PCZwAC/BmAEExOoyA3t0DdHVtKWQ6JBh9WAPTEFVZ9Rr32fIY06IVqSCQH1YQG5DCsC3GvLYTgmBqNYVIBgaT3HdK8TIQJwTQnAFQGmF0iUj4QHwMQK4Pi5zQkmRfNBUI0V9NofE8giTkmpPIPw%2BQ9BoEuj9IGNE/p6CAjbGQjJjLSnqM0doqVejEAQBQBM7ocJRmmMtdalJKh2DAH%2BP2cgczrygKWSs05ayXhbPIDsvZhzjnXIeE6q5pybnFBTEUdRpynmoBef6v4XzPG/P%2BS45gTq0BorBRC%2BA0LYV1zjYiqyyLUVMPRZi7FuK9AhEJcS0l2B0QsAKDKf0R90QUtFNSiQtKSZCPIV0zx9CWUhMBGEp1kTolmCtHy0oorGBQhhFaixSIfGhkYQIfgkreEyo%2BJYjK/CeC8kSryegP5eQuidCeq9PAzC9l1aIhgrr9W9LKUaypg6eDDtOaU41e6iiLLriAQEQA), I also put the count in a separate function that counts a `vector<int>&`, so we don't have to wade through the timing and `cout` code-gen in `main`.)

- branchy code: gcc8.2 `-O2` or `-O3`, and `O2/3 -march=haswell` or `broadwell`
- branchless code: gcc8.2 `-O2/3 -march=skylake`.

That's weird.  The branchless code it emits has the same cost on Broadwell vs. Skylake.  I wondered if Skylake vs. Haswell was favouring branchless because of cheaper `cmov`.  GCC's internal cost model isn't always in terms of x86 instructions when its optimizing in the middle-end (in GIMPLE, an architecture-neutral representation).  It doesn't yet know what x86 instructions would actually be used for a branchless sequence.  So maybe a conditional-select operation is involved, and gcc models it as more expensive on Haswell, where `cmov` is 2 uops?  But I tested `-march=broadwell` and still got branchy code.  Hopefully we can rule that out assuming gcc's cost model knows that Broadwell (not Skylake) was the first Intel P6/SnB-family uarch to have single-uop `cmov`, `adc`, and `sbb` (3-input integer ops).

I don't know what else about gcc's Skylake tuning option that makes it favour branchless code for this loop.  Gather is efficient on Skylake, but gcc is auto-vectorizing (with `vpgatherqd xmm`) even with `-march=haswell`, where it doesn't look like a win because gather is expensive, and and requires 32x64 => 64-bit SIMD multiplies using 2x `vpmuludq` per input vector.  Maybe worth it with SKL, but I doubt HSW.  Also probably a missed optimization not to pack back down to dword elements to gather twice as many elements with nearly the same throughput for `vpgatherdd`.

I did rule out the function being less optimized because it was called `main` (and marked `cold`).  It's generally recommended not to put your microbenchmarks in `main`: compilers at least used to optimize `main` differently (e.g. for code-size instead of just speed).

---

Clang does make it branchless even with just `-O2`.

---

**When compilers have to decide between branching and branchy, they have heuristics that guess which will be better**.  If they think it's highly predictable (e.g. probably mostly not-taken), that leans in favour of branchy.

In this case, the heuristic could have decided that out of all 2^32 possible values for an `int`, finding exactly the value you're looking for is rare.  The `==` may have fooled gcc into thinking it would be predictable.

Branchy can be better sometimes, depending on the loop, because it can break a data dependency.  See [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2) for a case where it *was* very predictable, and the `-O3` branchless code-gen was slower.

`-O3` at least used to be more aggressive at if-conversion of conditionals into branchless sequences like `cmp` ; `lea 1(%rbx), %rcx`; `cmove %rcx, %rbx`, or in this case more likely `xor`-zero / `cmp`/ `sete` / `add`.  (Actually gcc `-march=skylake` uses `sete` / `movzx`, which is pretty much strictly worse.)

Without any runtime profiling / instrumentation data, these guesses can easily be wrong.  **Stuff like this is where Profile Guided Optimization shines**.  Compile with `-fprofile-generate`, run it, then compiler with `-fprofile-use`, and you'll probably get branchless code.

---

BTW, `-O3` is generally recommended these days.  [Is optimisation level -O3 dangerous in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546075/is-optimisation-level-o3-dangerous-in-g).  It does *not* enable `-funroll-loops` by default, so it only bloats code when it auto-vectorizes (especially with very large fully-unrolled scalar prologue/epilogue around a *tiny* SIMD loop that bottlenecks on loop overhead.  /facepalm.)

Comment: I tried -O3 now, same output, just different offsets, will see now with -fno-tree-vectorize

Comment: btw forgot to mention I am using mavx, maybe it assumes certain arch that is different from my AMD...

Comment: I tried with -fno-tree-vectorize also, it did not change the asm at all,perf is not changed  noticeably...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: `-mavx` has zero impact on tuning decisions (choices between two sequences which don't require AVX).  That's why you should always use `-march=haswell` or `-march=znver1` instead of just `-mavx2`, for example, especially if you do plan to run on a specific CPU.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Odd that `-O3` didn't help; I thought it would.  I'll update this answer once you have a [mcve] that compiles this way.  What gcc version are you using?  Also, try using profile-guided optimization; maybe gcc incorrectly guesses at compile time that this branch will predict well.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Looks like a missed-optimization, but interestingly `-march=skylake` gives us branchless code.

Comment: Moving to GCC 8,1 and using mtune=skylake worked(I do not have skylake cpu so march skylake = dead exe)... Upvoted, but I will still leave this question open... Since it is quite bizzare that GCC would have this big codegen bug  without some good reason... :/ But for now I do not see any good reason.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Did you try using profile-guided optimization with another tuning? e.g. `-march=native`  That solved the problem in the other case, in the linked question where `-O3` was slower than `-O2`.

Comment: it is buggy on windows:  
[New Thread 4108.0x5f4]
[New Thread 4108.0x5dc]
[New Thread 4108.0xfa4]
[New Thread 4108.0xb88]
warning: Can not parse XML library list; XML support was disabled at compile time

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000550fc7 in std::random_device::_M_getval_pretr1() ()
(gdb) exit

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: yeah, I just tried it, too.  It's faster with PGO on my machine (gcc7.3 `-O3` with the default tune=generic), because it lays out the branch better.  The branch is *very* predictable, though, at least on Skylake.  `perf stat` says the program as a whole has 0.16% branch mispredict rate for a branchy version.  It's not surprising that PGO kept the branch, because it predicts very well.  `-march=skylake` (branchless) is slightly faster, though, so it turns out to have been the wrong choice I guess. (~722M clock cycles branchless, ~790M PGO, 814M plain -O3.)

Comment: for me it is quite bizarre, large program that I originally used gets diff perf based on mtune skylake/broadwell, but min example i posted does not... :/

Comment: also regarding branches: i made mistake in my godbolt link: found/not found alternate regularly, I should have used rand() when creating lookups...

Comment: btw when I try the min example now with randomized lookups skylake is 3x faster than broadwell, so sorry about giving you wrong test data...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Can you post a godbolt link for that version?  I'll try it with PGO.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: That is weird, gcc 7.3 isn't making branchless code even with `-O3 -mtune=skylake`, not even with PGO.  I'm seeing a 3.4% branch-mispredict rate.  (I realized my earlier testing with `-O3 -march=skylake` was auto-vectorizing; that's probably why it was just slightly faster!  Indeed, with the randomized version it's also faster, because SKL has fast gathers.)

Comment: I am using GCC 8.1 since per our earlier discussions I concluded that 7.3 I was using before would not generate branchless code even with skylake mtune...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: But clang's scalar branchless code is almost exactly as fast as gcc's auto-vectorized code.  I'm still getting 1.8% branch mispredicts, so there's some unpredictable branching somewhere other than in the comparison?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: g++7.3 on Godbolt does make branchless code with `-mtune=skylake` for the source I linked in my answer.  Maybe a different config or something?  Or maybe a slightly different revision of g++7.3 than I have on my desktop.  Oh, or maybe a different `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: I am on windows, so I did not profile the code... but like I said in my original question I noticed the slowdown when condition is true only 50% of the cases, otherwise(10%, 90%) it works fast. And in this small program IDK where else would be time be spent between timing start and timing end...

Comment: just double checked: if I do rand()%12 instead of rand()%2 in lookup generation difference drops from almost 3x to 1.4x... So it is the branching that causes the diff between skylake and broadwell mtune on GCC 8.1 -O2

Comment: also I just did PGO, with broadwell mtune, it did not help... :/

Comment: anyway, I think we can agree it is kind of a codegen bug most likely.... but like I said it is weird that GCC would have bug of this severity... But then again maybe I was just unlucky and it does not affect 99.9999% of the compiles.